# GPG encryption date or GPG version recoverable?

Tags: pgp, file-encryption, gnupg, data-recovery

Is there a way to determine the date of encryption or the GPG version of a GPG-encrypted file (with symmetric encryption)?

I lost the password but some rough information about when the file was encrypted would help me. (The oldest could be 5-7 years ago, newest a few months. The file modification time is also lost.)

For example, if I remember right, it could be that old versions of GPG did not have integrity checking. Can I figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

If the file is ASCII armored, you may find the header at the top.

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.11 (GNU/Linux)

jA0EAwMCSPY2a+zUrBBgySD3+GWiPhdcQbtKogerjG/50O9Q6f3FY78qqyxLBw00
RA==
=DBXE
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

If it isn't then you can try to review the specification, but it's complicated and after several minutes of reading I don't have a clear answer either. See  http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4880.txt.

Comment: Thanks, and according to old package descriptions, gpg 1.4.6, the version I likely had used, if the file is old, is compatible with RFC2440. But I'm still deciding if it's too much effort. (Though, generally also an interesting security question, I think)